# ng-controller App data not binding properly

Tags: angularjs

I have to finish this assignment. I am trying to print out the contacts in contactsController and be able to add to this list. I can't figure out where I am going wrong. Can anyone help. I have an array contacts[] in contactController and I am trying to print out the list in html using ng-repeat="contact in contactsController.contacts" and binding to contact.name and contact.type.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
<style>
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="contactsController">
<label>Name</label>
    <input ng-model="contactsController.contacts.name" type="text" placeholder="Name">
<label>email</label>
<input ng-model="contactsController.email" type="text" placeholder="Email">
<button ng-click="addContact()">Add contact</button>
</div>
<div>{{contactsController.name}}</div>
<div>
    <ul>

        <li ng-repeat="contact in contactsController.contacts">
            <div>{{contact.name}}</div>
            <div>{{contact.email}}</div>
            <div><button ng-click="deleteContact($index)">delete</button></div>
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
    <script>
// Your code goes here.

    // $( document ).ready(function() {
    //  alert('jQuery asdfas!');
// Your code here.
// });
function contactsController($scope){
    $scope.contacts=[{name:'asdf',email:'asdf'},
    {name:'yweuir',email:'xcvzx'}
    ];
    contactsController.prototype.addContact =function($scope){
        console.log(this.name);
        console.log(this.email);
        this.contacts.push({name:this.name,email:this.email});
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your repeat is wrong. It should be:

```
ng-repeat="contact in contacts"
```

When you are doing a repeat, the reference to the array assumes it's in $scope already. Your controller has nothing to do with it. So if you had:

```
$scope.contractsController = {
  contacts: {...}
}
```

Your code would work. But your controller is fine, just remove the reference from the repeat.

Comment: it still doesn't print anything. could something else be wrong.

Comment: it works now. I was terminating the ng-controller div early and the data binding expression was outisde the scope of the controller

Comment: Oh! Man I didn't even consider that part. But yeah, @carlosmantilla did work!

Answer (score 1):

I'll create a plunker so you can check the detail changes in the revisions.

http://plnkr.co/edit/NrbLiIFw4EbxEfYJm41J?p=preview

The HTML had a wrong indentation, and the ng-repeat was outside of the ng-controller block.

Also, was missing the injection of the controller into the module of the application, i rewrote the application using the general application declaration with ngApp directive.

If you want an example more detailed you can check the TodoMVC angular application
https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/tree/gh-pages/architecture-examples/angularjs-perf

Other examples:
http://todomvc.com/architecture-examples/angularjs/#/

All the best

Answer (score 1):

**Hey**  I'll create a plnkr link.

Here is link Check this:

```
 http://plnkr.co/edit/mzcAC5yU9P6Mb3nfGByP?p=preview
```

Here is Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app = "app">
 <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js"> 
  </script>
  <script>
   angular.module("app",[]).controller('contactsController',['$scope', 
    function($scope) {
     $scope.contacts=[{name:'Abhi',email:'Abhi@test.com'},
        {name:'Sharma',email:'sharma@test.com'}
     ];
     $scope.addContact =function(){
      this.contacts.push({name:this.name,email:this.email});
      $scope.name = '';
      $scope.email = '';
     }
     $scope.deleteContact = function (index) {
      $scope.contacts.splice(index, 1);
     }
    }
   ]);
  </script>
 </head>
<body ng-controller="contactsController">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input ng-model="name" type="text" placeholder="Name">
    <label>email</label>
    <input ng-model="email" type="text" placeholder="Email">
    <button ng-click="addContact()">Add contact</button>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="contact in contacts">
        <div>{{contact.name}}</div>
        <div>{{contact.email}}</div>
        <div><button ng-click="deleteContact($index)">delete</button></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

May be it help you..
   Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't prefix your values with the controller name.  The `ng-controller` section basically sets the scope for the child elements to an instance of the controller.  So what's happening in your code currently is that it's checking the `contactsController` for an attribute of `contactsController`.